# APIView - How to raise a 400 Bad Request and be caught by the exception handler

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to raise a BadRequest error in my APIView and I wish it to be caught by the custom exception handler I have created.

My current setup doesn't catch the exception. Could I please have some help as to why this may be happening

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     ......
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'src.exceptions.common_exception_handler',
}
```

views.py

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

exceptions.py

````
def common_exception_handler(exc: APIException, context: dict) -> Response:
    response = origin_exception_handler(exc, context)
    .............
```
````

Comment: You are not raising any exceptions in your view, so why should it be caught by a exception handler? what are you trying to do here? the obvious answer is the code `raise_exception=False` that ofc makes the validation explicitly not raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying not to raise an exception directly by my serializer (hence setting raise_exception=False)

And then i thought by calling and exception would be raised because its a BAD_REQUEST
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

But i guess I am wrong :) How would I accomplish what I am trying to do ?

Comment: If you want the response to be handled by the exception handler just raise an exception - if you want to handle it yourself then do what you are doing now.